# How to include tabbar and navigation controller in single app?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How to create a tabbar Controller and Navigation Bar Controller in a window based app? I am trying to include both controllers.

Comment: You should just add to your tab `UINavigationController` with appropriate `UIView` as a `rootViewController` of `UINavigationController`

Comment: @Vishal :If you like the answer, try to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows...
Create project of navigationController type..
then in AppDelegate , create a tabBarController. Have an array of you Viewcontrollers as follows...

```
mTabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *localViewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];


    TSDetailTaskController *mTSDetailTaskController = [[TSDetailTaskController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TSDetailTaskController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *mTaskNavBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mTSDetailTaskController];
    mTaskNavBar.tabBarItem.title=@"Task List";
    mTaskNavBar.tabBarItem.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"glyphicons_114_list.png"];
    [mTSDetailTaskController release];

    mTSSearchController=[[TSSearchController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TSSearchController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *mSearchNavBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mTSSearchController];
    mSearchNavBar.title=@"Search";
    mSearchNavBar.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"glyphicons_009_search.png"];
    [mTSSearchController release];

    TSSettingController *mTSSettingController = [[TSSettingController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TSSettingController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *mSettingNavBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mTSSettingController];
    mSettingNavBar.tabBarItem.title=@"Setting";
    mSettingNavBar.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"glyphicons_280_settings.png"];
    [mTSSettingController release];


    [localViewControllersArray addObject:mTaskNavBar];  
    [localViewControllersArray addObject:mSearchNavBar];
    [localViewControllersArray addObject:mSettingNavBar];

    [mTaskNavBar release];
    [mSearchNavBar release];
    [mSettingNavBar release];


    mTabBar.viewControllers = localViewControllersArray;
    mTabBar.view.autoresizingMask==(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

    [localViewControllersArray release];


    [window addSubview:mTabBar.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

hope this will help you out..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of viewcontrollers, add navigation contollers as each item for the tabbarcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in the Interface Builder, just make sure the Tabbar controller is the root/master controller and inside it you can add as many navControllers as you need. Of course, the tabbar controller is the one added to the Window in the AppDelegate.m file.
I you dont want the tabbar to be visible from the begining, you can implement `self.tabbarcontroller.tabbar.hidden = YES;` in the viewDidLoad or `viewWillAppear` methods of each of the views you dont want the tabbar on.